# How to put line break in mpdf when data is extracted from mysql database

Tags: multiline, mpdf

I am using MPDF to generate pdf files from data stored in mysql database. Though I could extract and display others data as expected, I could not display multiline text as they all comes in single line. Could someone help me to resolve this problem.

EG. My data from textarea is shown in database as:
One

Two

Three

But in pdf it will ge generated as OneTwoThree

When I check in database using phpmyadmin its stored data as One\r\nTwo\r\nThree

Please help.

Answer (score 4):

Try with this code.
$finalString = nl2br($htmlOut);

Answer (score 2):

MPDF is for generating PDF from HTML.

HTML shows your lines as OneTwoThree, because it does not care about line breaks. You should change the '\r\n' to HTML line breaks.

```
$finalString = str_replace("\r\n", "<br />", $htmlOut");
```

Comment: I have html line breaks, they are rendered simply as `<br>` without actually breaking the line.