# Every enter keys in textarea should be displayed in pdf format

Tags: javascript, php, pdf

I have text area as below

[image: this is how my text area is]

```
<textarea placeholder="Booking Details " name="particular" rows="4" ></textarea>
```

and on submit button I want to submit full content of text area as it is on next page from which pdf is generated. I am using php code to pass data from one page to another, but as I type something with enter key in text area, on pdf it comes in one line.

[image: this is my pdf]

Please help me out with php or javascript code.

Comment: Please chekc this link if any helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099661/enter-key-in-textarea

Comment: Depends on library and approach used to create the pdf. Not enough known

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find this answer - you can directly post finalString to url php page now -

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  var finalString="";
  
  $('#txtArea').on('keyup',function(event){
    var code = event.which;
    if(code===13){
      finalString =finalString+"'/r/n'";
      }
   else if(code!==8)
     {
        finalString =finalString+event.key;
       }
       
  });
$('button').on('click',function(){
  $('div').text(finalString)
  
  
})

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea placeholder="Booking Details " name="particular" rows="4" id="txtArea"></textarea>
<button>submit</button>
<div id='finalString'></div>
```

Comment: these both above code should be placed in main page right?

Comment: Yes...just get final string from your text area as above and send it to your pdf making library. that's it.Just be sure about enter key string once again

Answer (score -1):

Its problem of css. Use property white-space: pre-wrap in your output div -

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('button').on('click',function(){
var txt = $('#txtArea').val();
  $('div').text(txt);
  
})

});
```

```css
div
{
  white-space: pre-wrap 
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea placeholder="Booking Details " name="particular" rows="4" id="txtArea"></textarea>
<button>submit</button>
<div></div>
```

Comment: but my pdf generation code is in other php page
please specify me, where to place javacript code

Comment: @Akshaya - you must be displaying entered text,  before generating it to pdf, right???

Comment: @Akshaya - try to add css to that page where you displaying entered text and then convert it into pdf.

Comment: i have used that white-space:pre wrap as

Comment: <div style="white-space:pre-wrap;"><?php echo $particular;?></div>

Comment: which library you are using to generate pdf??

Comment: I will tel you in detail how it works, i have a page name as "index.php" in which i have created one form which contains data with a textarea. Then when i click on submit button it goes to next page named as pdf-project.php. On this page , i have one php code to insert data in db and also to generate pdf as mydata.pdf. So pdf-project.php is the hidden page, when i click submit it shows my pdf mydata.pdf. When i see text area in pdf it comes in one line. please help.\

Comment: i am using mpdf library

Comment: Please refer this.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24322530/how-to-put-line-break-in-mpdf-when-data-is-extracted-from-mysql-database. in your case you have to manully insert '\r\n' in your string whenever enter key is pressed through javascript.

Comment: Though , i dont know much about mpdf. if mentioned link is solution in your case then you can easily insert '\r\n' whenever enter key is pressed by javascript, and then you can pass that string to your mpdf library

Comment: i have added 2 more images in my above question, about how it looks live. you can check that

Comment: if you want any help to insert '\r\n' through javascript. let me know

Comment: then i think i have to replace every space from 1st page to some character and again to replace dat character to space in 2nd page

Comment: if you can help me in replacing character code in javascript then it wil be very helpful to me

Comment: @Akshaya - i have posted answer now. Please check