# Use line break in mPDF when data is from mysql table

Tags: mysql, line-breaks, mpdf

I'm using mPDF to display data from mysql database. It happens the mPDF can't display the line break.

In database data is like :

one

two

three

the mPDF displays like this : one two three

I found an answer in this page :[[How to put line break in mpdf when data is extracted from mysql database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24322530/how-to-put-line-break-in-mpdf-when-data-is-extracted-from-mysql-database][1])

But this cannot solve my problem.

My PHP CODE

```
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf(['tempDir' => __DIR__ . '/custom/temp/dir/path','format' => 'A5']);

$sql ="SELECT * FROM  table";
$this->data['dataTable']= $this->db->query($sql);

$html = $this->load->view('admin/print/cirugia_toracia_report',$this->data,true);

$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);

$mpdf->Output();
```

Some helps is greatly appreciated

Comment: Where do you use the mentioned answer in your code? There is no nl2br used in your example.

Comment: Your are right, I thought that it was the mPDF charge to do the job, but I realize that it is the php to do it. nl2br($row->detail). Thank you so much

Comment: Sure. Consider accepting and upvoting the answer I just added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert line breaks to `<br>` HTML tags. Call `nl2br` function over the data you want to convert.

```
$this->data['dataTable']['column_to_break'] = nl2br($this->data['dataTable']['column_to_break']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this please (TRUE big)

```
$data = $this->db->query($sql);
$html = $this->load->view('admin/print/cirugia_toracia_report',$data, TRUE);
```

Or

```
$html = $this->load->view('admin/print/cirugia_toracia_report',$this->data, TRUE);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, the fisrt option cannot display the data in the view, because I have to use $cirugia_toracico->result() as $row.  The second option doesn't work neither